# Windows phone 8 life tile using the title to show the user some information

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I was wondering if the font color of the life tile has to be white in all cases.

Basically I like to update my tile title at a specific time using TileUpdateManager and TileNotification to show the user some information (like an alarm time)

I have downloaded so many apps now and all tile titles are in white.

I am not sure If I am on the right track wanting to update the app tile title using another font color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/design/jj662929(v=vs.105).aspx , there is no possibility of changing the default text color in the Live Tiles - the font color is white, because is the only color that matches on all the accents color.

The reason of this choice is quite clear. You just have to imagine a phone with dark blue accent color on the tiles and black text: this would make the tile content unreadable.

By the way, using the font color to notify the user on something is the worst way to do it, when you have a whole Live Tile to use. You may choose to display a different image, write different text, and so on; this changes would be much more effective for the user than a mere font color change.

My suggestion is to read this article on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/jj662929(v=vs.105).aspx . Here you can find many relevant suggestions on how to design your Live Tile and how to be effective in displaying information to the user.

I also suggest you not to use Tiles for important notifications, like alarms, as MSDN documentation states:

> "Don't rely on Tiles to send urgent, real-time info to the user. For
>   instance, a Tile is not the right surface for a communication app to
>   inform the user of an incoming call. Toast notifications are a better
>   medium for real-time messages."

Comment: Thank's very much for you clarification. About the white font color- my company has it's logo on white background which ideally we do not want to loose, however the app name should be visible of course. The only way to solve that would then be to add a non-white background on the bottom of the tile. So I do not change the font color to inform the user and certainly agree this would not be a good approach :-) All I like to do is have some VISIBLE text in the tile that informs the user at a specific time - but I guess that is not possible without a server. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly, but you can generate an image and use that as your tile - then you can display it however you want.  See [this blog post](http://windcape.posterous.com/how-to-generate-a-custom-live-tile-directly-o) for an example.

I'll echo threddeveloper's advice not to us the tiles to display important notifications, however.

Comment: I am using WP8 not WP7. Changing the app tile title can be done using the BackgroundAgent directly, however the remaining question is whether it is possible to change the app title text at a specific time - like a local notification on iOS or Android for example. Many thanks